# Opening a div in a {{/if}} and closing it later with meteor/blaze

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, meteor, meteor-blaze

I'm trying to make something that is not possible in HTML/Blaze only.

By that I mean that I'm trying to open a div in a {{#if}} without closing it in this specific if. Impossible to do it the following way :

```
{{#each getData}}
    {{#if equals this.level first}}
        <div><p>content</p>
    {{/if}}
    {{#if equals this.level last}}
        </div>
    {{/if}}}
{{/each}}
```

So I found something that could solve this problem. Using triple curly braces and generate the HTML part in JS.

```
{{#each getData}}
    {{{getContent this}}}
{{/each}}
```

getContent() return my HTML. It looks like this :

```
getContent(obj) {
    if (obj.level == first)
        return "<div><p>content</p>";
    if (obj.level == last)
        return "<p>content></div>";
    else
        return "<p>content</p>";
}
```

It works, it render the HTML, but there is one problem. The div I'm opening seems to close itself.

This is what's rendered :

```
<div><p>Content</p></div>
<p>content</p>
<p>content</p>
```

instead of :

```
<div><p>content</p>
     <p>content</p>
     <p>content</p>
</div
```

I'm really tired, I apologize if I'm not clear enough or if the solution is obvious.

EDIT: What I have now, and it's working fine, is the following :

HTML

```
{{#with getDataFromButton}}
    {{formatData this}}
{{/with}}
```

JS

```
formatData(data) {
        var res = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i]["level"] == 0) {
                if (res.length > 0)
                    res += "</div>";
                res += "<div class=\"whiteBox\"><p>" + data[i]["value"] + "</p>";
            }
            else if ('last' in data[i]) {
                res += "<p>" + data[i]["value"] + "</p></div>";
            }
            else {
                res += "<p>" + data[i]["value"] + "</p>";
            }
        }
        return res;
    },
```

Thanks to all of you for the explanations ! And happy new year (it's not too late).

Comment: why not move it outside the ifs (but inside the each)?  In your current way you could end up with lots of opened divs with no closed divs or vice versa

Comment: It won't open to much div since there is always a last element and only one associated parent. So it will first open it and when the last is processed it should close it.

Comment: But still you have that chance, so just moving them outside the ifs will have the same effect and makes your code more maintainable for others coming to it in future

Comment: If you injecting string to dom by blaze (for example by {{{ }}}) it should be valid HTML node, in another way a browser close this or remove closing tags exactly like in your example.

Comment: Yes but it wouldn't allows me to do what I want. I have an array of object that have a value and a level, multiple parents with associated children. I don't want to put the whole data in one div, just to separate it into multiple divs.

Comment: @Daniel, are you saying I can't do it ?

Comment: You can do tricks like this on the server side, because of when your template is generating nobody check if it is valid. But in your case, any single blaze element of a template is injecting independent strings to browser dom. Try to do it manually in pure JS. The browser will fix it anyway. You can use template strings and render all your code in JS memory and inject when the last div will be closed. I will update my answer and show you.

Comment: Well, I’m doing it on the client side, I might need to do it in the server side then. My supervisor did it almost exactly the same way so I know it’s possible.

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to do this. You should rethink how your HTML works. It's never a good idea for one block of code to open a tag, and leave it open. Whether or not you *can* do it is moot, it's not *supposed* to work because it's such a bad practice.

Comment: I agree with @megar. Even if in 2004 in PHP people was using this approach and this syntax was popular, now it is considered as bad practice. And the idea with server rendering, in this case, seems to be wrong. Notice that although you can use server-side rendering with Meteor, with blase it is impossible. In some cases, server-side rendering can speed up application, but mixing it with the blaze in this case probably will cause more problems than it is worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done because of browser try to fix HTML structure on any change. If you using Blaze, then HTML is rendered on the client side and in any evaluation of your helper code is injected to DOM. Then browser gets this HTML and tries to fix it.

Best solution is use simple pattern

```
<div>
{{#each getData}}
     <p>content</p>
{{/each}}
</div>
```

If you want to apply the logic that you presented you *have to* prepare full correct HTML element in JS. You can to it as follow.

In template type: {{ myFullCorrectNodeElement }}

In JS type:

```
helpers: {
   myFullCorrectNodeElement() {
      let html = "";
      const data = Template.instance().getData;
      for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
          // your logic
          if(i===0) {
             html += `<div><p>content</p>`  
             // there you can access to variables by syntax ${}
             // insde of ``, you can read about template strings from ES6
          }  
          // ... and rest of your logic
      }
      return html; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, I guess I’ll have to do that, I’ll try and tomorrow !